# Form Grid serializerController can't render my column value when load

Tags: grid, grid-serlization

I have Grid which has 4 serialzed input it could be look something like

Below is just eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new serializerController('id_27b4a99055d89f87349b56c924404a36', {"1":{"price":"0,000","position":"4"},"2":{"price":"14,000","position":"5"}}, ["price","position"], specificationGrid_1JsObject, 'specifications');
```

But my controller object contain like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new serializerController('id_f0526caaa5cb152f3a0282ec6884026e', [1605,1730,1977,2121], ["shouldsendwarrantymail","shouldsendfactorymail","shouldsendordermail"], customerGridJsObject, 'customer');
```

**My Grid File.**

```
<?php
class Shipping_Shippinggroup_Block_Adminhtml_Shippinggroup_Edit_Tab_Formcustomer extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
        $this->setAdditionalJavaScript("
        // added click on selectbox support
        serializerController.prototype.rowClick = serializerController.prototype.rowClick.wrap(function(o, grid, event) {
            var tagName = Event.element(event).tagName
                isSelect = (tagName == 'SELECT' || tagName == 'OPTION');
            if (!isSelect) {
                o(grid, event);
            }
        });
        ");
    }



    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $groupId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id',array('in' => array(5)));
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}



    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('customer_ids', array(
            'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
            'type'              => 'checkbox',
            'name'              => 'customer_ids',
            'values'            => $this->_getSelectedCustomers(),
            'align'             => 'center',
            'index'             => 'entity_id'
        ));


        $this->addColumn('shouldsendwarrantymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Warranty Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,


        ));

        $this->addColumn('shouldsendfactorymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Factory Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));
        $this->addColumn('shouldsendordermail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Order Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));


        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row) {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _getSelectedCustomers()   // Used in grid to return selected customers values.
    {
        $customers = $this->getSelectedCustomers();
        return $customers;
    }

    public function getSelectedCustomers()
    {
        // Customer Data

        $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if(!isset($tm_id)) {
            $tm_id = 0;
        }

            $custIds = array();
            $customerProductIds = Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroupcustomer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('shippinggroup_id', array(
                     array('finset' => $tm_id)));
                    // print_r($customerProductIds->getData());
            foreach($customerProductIds as $id){
                $custIds[$id->getCustomerIds()] = array(
                                                        'shouldsendwarrantymail' => $id->getShouldsendwarrantymail(),
                                                        'shouldsendfactorymail' => $id->getShouldsendfactorymail(),
                                                        'shouldsendordermail' => $id->getshouldsendordermail(),
                                                        );
            }

        //var_dump($custIds);exit;
        return array_keys($custIds);
    }

    /**
     * Rerieve grid URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/customergrid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

**Layout file**

```
<shippinggroup_adminhtml_shippinggroup_customers>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="shippinggroup/adminhtml_shippinggroup_edit_tab_formcustomer" name="shippinggroup.edit.tab.formcustomer" />
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="customer_grid_serializer" >
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>shippinggroup.edit.tab.formcustomer</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedCustomers</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[customer_ids]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>customer</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                   <input_name>shouldsendwarrantymail</input_name>
                   <input_name>shouldsendfactorymail</input_name>
                   <input_name>shouldsendordermail</input_name>
               </action>
        </block>
    </block>
</shippinggroup_adminhtml_shippinggroup_customers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the answer from my self.

```
 public function getSelectedCustomers()
{
    // Customer Data

    $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    if(!isset($tm_id)) {
        $tm_id = 0;
    }

        $custIds = array();
        $customerProductIds = Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroupcustomer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('shippinggroup_id', array(
                 array('finset' => $tm_id)));
                // print_r($customerProductIds->getData());
        foreach($customerProductIds as $id){
            $custIds[$id->getCustomerIds()] = array(
                                                    'shouldsendwarrantymail' => $id->getShouldsendwarrantymail(),
                                                    'shouldsendfactorymail' => $id->getShouldsendfactorymail(),
                                                    'shouldsendordermail' => $id->getshouldsendordermail(),
                                                    );
        }


    return $custIds; /* it should return full array */
}
```

**For column value**

```
$this->addColumn('customer_ids', array(
        'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
        'type'              => 'checkbox',
        'name'              => 'customer_ids',
        'values'            => array_keys($this->_getSelectedCustomers()),
        'align'             => 'center',
        'index'             => 'entity_id'
    ));
```

**Important function from layout file**

```
<data_callback>getSelectedCustomers</data_callback>
```

above define function is responsible to generate json